# Spring Boot - Large Text Properties

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Years ago on a different project, we were able to import easily large xml property files with all the custom queries we needed that could not be generated, safely wrapped in CDATA tags. Have not found the similar option in Spring Boot.
Here is what we currently have:

```
@Value("classpath:sql/query.sql")
private Resource queryFile;

private String query;

@PostConstruct
public void loadNewSQL() throws IOException {
  InputStream is = queryFile.getInputStream();
  this.query = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(is);
}
```

Previously, it was config for one file and all the content were accessible by the @Value annotation. Still cannot find the modern equivalent.

Comment: The best oprion would be to use `liquibase/flyway` for that instead doing it via bean `PostConstruct`

Comment: @AntonNovopashin I understand that, but it is not just for SQL queries. We also have large metadata files as well. I was hoping for something similar to the old pattern of having a resource file and accessing entries as whatever the key was with @Value("key").